# Get password of archive file knowing its contents

Tags: encryption, archive, 7zip

Is it possible to get .7z archive password when you have password protected archive file and decrypted content of that archive file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the password is easy and short, the best way is to try brute-force it.
Look at http://telecharger.tomsguide.fr/ZIP-Ultimate-Cracker,0301-1445.html

Comment: Yes, it helped me but because of easy password. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Ubuntu, Please have a look at the link below.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/13474/how-do-i-extract-a-password-protected-7z-file